# Confused about when saving a variable using the $() function

Tags: jquery

In jQuery, if I do this:

```
var a = $("#someid");
```

Now when I need to further reference using jQuery, what should I be doing?

```
$(a).attr("id");
```

or

```
a.attr("id");
```

I'm testing things out and I'm getting confused, just want the official word so I can rule this out.

Comment: The second method is what you should do: `a.attr("id")`

Comment: Also, (although not necessary), I think it's a good idea to prefix variables that have jQuery objects assigned to them with a dollar sign.  `var $a = $("#someid")`.  That lets you know later on without a doubt that its a jQuery object.

Comment: Did you receive an acceptable answer to your question?

Answer (score 9):

This one:

```
a.attr("id");
```

since `a` is already a jQuery object.

Although it is a convention used by many to prefix variables that reference a jQuery object with `$`.

So:

```
var $a = $("#someid");
$a.attr("id");
```

This is only a common convention, and not a requirement. I think it adds clarity, but that may be just because I'm pretty conditioned to look for the `$` by now.

Comment: I usually prepend the name of variables that contain a jQuery object with $ because of this (ie. `$a`).

Comment: I'm borderline about that convention. I think it only clutters the variable names if used blindly. Only use it when both jQuery objects and regular html elements are used. Otherwise it's just like naming our variables intA, strName, etc...

Answer (score 3):

Both will work but `$(a)` will have no effect, so is a wasted function call.

Comment: Your conclusion that it is a wasted call is absolutely correct (+1), but there is a *minor* effect that it can have. Because re-wrapping it results in a new jQuery object, any reference to previous state that `.end()` would provide is lost. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/U62ut/) (if you don't mind a few `alert()`). I think it would be pretty rare that it would make a difference, but still worth pointing out. :o)

Comment: @patrick, good point. Rare situation as you say, but always good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

Using your example, the second option is correct.

```
var a = $("#someid");
a.attr("id");
```

You can use the first option too, but because `a` is already a jquery object, its pointless.